# Laravel Auth in static class "Non-static method" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm making class that handles boring auth stuff in one file.
But I'm having small problem here with calling auth functions.

First problem I encounter is with this function:

```
hasTooManyLoginAttempts
```

Code

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
```

Triggers error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

When I change $this-> to self::

```
if (self::hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
```

Triggers

```
Non-static method My\AuthClass::hasTooManyLoginAttempts() should not be called statically
```

Example class I'm trying to work with

```
namespace My\AuthClass;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthClass
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public static function doLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate login

        // Has too many login attempts?

        if (self::hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            self::fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return redirect()->route('login.show')->with('error', 'You have tried to login too many times in short amount of time. Please try again later.');
        }

        // Try authenticate

        // Send login error
    }
}
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: I think you are trying to create a facade, but they work a little bit differently in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades should help you on your way. If you follow the documentation you no longer need to make the methods static (which causes your errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public static function doLogin(Request $request)` is obviously a static function while `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` is not.

You can't call it using the double colon and you can't use `$this` in static context. Quite the predicament.

You'll have to create a sort of workaround:

```
class AuthClass
{
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  private static $instance = null;

  public static function doLogin(Request $request)
  {
    // Validate login

    $self = self::init();

    // Has too many login attempts?
    if ($self->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
      $self->fireLockoutEvent($request);
      return redirect()->route('login.show')->with('error', 'You have tried to login too many times in short amount of time. Please try again later.');
    }

    // Try authenticate

    // Send login error
  }

  public static function init() {
    if(null === self::$instance) {
      self::$instance = new self;
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

The important part here is the new `init()` function(you can name it whatever you want). It will create a new instance of the current class and allow you to use `->` in "static" context(it's not really static).

---

As user Tuim pointed out in the comments, a facade could also work, but the "trick" is about the same.

Comment: Should work fine, except this is not "The Laravel way" of solving the issue, therefor decreasing maintainability for future developers.

Comment: Now with that I can agree. It's not the laravel way. Overall I agree with your facade approach, but I don't really know laravel good enough to provide that answer. I'd suggest you post an answer yourself and OP **should** accept your answer, not mine.